# ZXing only recognizes QR-Code

Tags: zxing, google-glass, barcode-scanner

I am trying to develop a barcode scanner for google glass (don't judge) using the [ZXing library](https://github.com/zxing/zxing).

Scanning QR-Codes works perfectly fine, but I can't scan any 1D-barcodes.

This is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CaptureActivity.class);
//intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE"); //doesn't work with or without this line
startActivityForResult(intent, SCAN_REQUEST);
```

Here is an example (EAN-8):

[image]

Scanning this with a scanner from the PlayStore works on my phone, but not using my app on the glass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround for my problem in the *DecodeRunnable.java*.
By adding `BarcodeFormat.EAN_8` to the list in the code below I was able to scan the barcode.

```
DecodeHandler() {
  hints = new EnumMap<>(DecodeHintType.class);
  hints.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS,
      Arrays.asList(BarcodeFormat.AZTEC, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX));
}
```

You are wellcome to post your answers, because I believe there is a better way to solve this.